# Does exists "business controls" for Java environment or for ..Linux?

Tags: java, linux, development-environment

i'm wondering if exists business control for Java environment or for ... Linux development.
Hi used to develop desktop application with .NET + external control by (for instance): Infragistics, DevExpress, ComponentOne etc. 
These controls are really powerful and comfortable to work with. I would like to develop database driven application also with Java so, i can run it in Linux environment, but the lack of external controls (or widget) is the reason i don't use Java. 
Am i wrong ? 
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm looking to find good "extension" for java that allow me to be productive.. i'm .net programmaer who want to pass also to java to develop database driven application.. My main request is to discover a some java grid controls like the ones i've mentionated above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some

http://www.jidesoft.com/products/download.htm

http://www.jgoodies.com/products/swingsuite.html

http://www.jgraph.com/

http://www.yworks.com/en/products.html

http://www.migcalendar.com/

Comment: Do you also know some poweful grid ?